# Why `depthfirst2` is always marked as red?

Tags: prolog, predicate, swi-prolog

Got the following program for depth search, however the `depthsearch` predicate is always marked as red, so I am unable to run the program. What is the issue?

```
node(a).
node(b).
node(c).
node(d).
node(e).
node(f).
node(g).
node(h).
node(i).
node(j).

s(a,b). s(a,c).
s(b,d). s(b,e).
s(c,f). s(c,g).
s(d,h).
s(e,i). s(e,j).
goal(j).
goal(f).

depthfirst2( Node, [Node], _) :-
    goal( Node).

depthfirst2( Node, [Node | Sol], Maxdepth) :-
    Maxdepth > 0,
    s( Node, Node1),
    Max1 is Maxdepth - 1,
    depthfirst2( Node1, Sol, Max1).
```

Comment: Is this on Swish? It marks in read anything that is not used within the same program/segment, so the one predicate you will actually call will be "marked in read" (as "not called" or "not used") I guess it is a bug/feature of Swish. The coloring as far as I know is the same that is used by the desktop IDE, where this coloring makes a bit more sense.

Comment: Not clear which prolog is being used and where you see "red".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working correctly.
Try calling the predicate as:

```
?-depthfirst2(a,L,4).

OUTPUT:
L = [a, b, e, j]
L = [a, c, f]
false
```